# Define Dynamic controller name variable from for loop in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have 20 input

```
  // A
  final a1Input = new TextEditingController();
  final a2Input = new TextEditingController();
  final a3Input = new TextEditingController();
  final a4Input = new TextEditingController();
  final a5Input = new TextEditingController();
  final a6Input = new TextEditingController();
  final a7Input = new TextEditingController();
  final a8Input = new TextEditingController();
  final a9Input = new TextEditingController();
  final a0Input = new TextEditingController();

  // B
  final b1Input = new TextEditingController();
  final b2Input = new TextEditingController();
  final b3Input = new TextEditingController();
  final b4Input = new TextEditingController();
  final b5Input = new TextEditingController();
  final b6Input = new TextEditingController();
  final b7Input = new TextEditingController();
  final b8Input = new TextEditingController();
  final b9Input = new TextEditingController();
  final b0Input = new TextEditingController();
```

so I made forloop for make it easy and fast

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
       var jData = {
        'number': i,
        'amount': a1Input.text, <= controller variable
      };
    }
```

how to define controller `a1Input.text` like `a$iInput.text`
but its not working
how can I define controller like that

I want to define controller name

Comment: make it a list, like: `final controllers = List.generate(10, (i) => TextEditingController());`

Comment: and then? how to add this to amount

Comment: then you use them in your text field like this: `TextFormField(controller: controllers[3], ...)`

Comment: thank you this could make my app more easy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this helps me

```
final aInput = List.generate(10, (i) => TextEditingController());
```

and made input controller like this

```
controller: aInput[0] to controller: aInput[9];
```

now i can define in for loop

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
      if (i == 0) {
        if (i == 0) {
          setState(() {
            nu = '10000';
          });
        }
      } else {
        if (i >= 1 && i <= 9) {
          setState(() {
            nu = '$i$i$i$i';
          });
        }
      }
      var hData = {
        'number': nu,
        'amount': aInput[i].text, <= Here
      };
      setState(() {
        if (aInput[i].text.isNotEmpty) {
          _harups.insertAll(0, [hData]);
        }
      });

      aInput[i].clear();
    }
```

Thanks @pskink for answer

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with map.

```
  Map<String, TextEditingController> allControllers = <String, TextEditingController>{
    "a1Input": a1Input,
    "a2Input": a2Input,
    "a3Input": a3Input,
    "a4Input": a4Input,
    .
    .
    .
  };

  for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
     var jData = {
      'number': i,
      'amount': allControllers['a$iInput'].text,
     };
  }
```